# Заменить в строке слово, при этом не затрагивая это же слово внутри кавычек

Tags: c++, строки

Как заменить в строке слово, при этом не затрагивая это же слово внутри кавычек?

Например:

Вход:

```
hello "hello test" hello
```

Выход:

```
world "hello test" world
```

Вот моя попытка:

```
string str = "test \"test hello\" test;"; 
int y; 
for(int x = 0;x<1024;x++) 
{ 
    if(str[x] == '"') { 
        y+=1; 
    } 
    if(str[x] == '\n') { 
        break; 
    } 
    if(str[x] == '\0') { 
        break; 
    } 
} 

y=y%2; 
for(int x = 0;x<1024;x++) { 
    if(str[x] == 't') { 
        if(str[x+1] == 'e') { 
            if(str[x+2] == 's') { 
                if(str[x+3] == 't') { 
                    if(y <= 1) { 
                        str.replace(str.find("test"), sizeof("test") - 1, "world"); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мы не находимся внутри кавычек и нашли нужное слово, то заменяем его на новое:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "test \"test hello\" test";

    const std::string oldSubstring = "test";
    const std::string newSubstring = "world"; 

    bool insideQuotes = false;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s[i] == '\"')
            insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;

        if (!insideQuotes)
            if (s.compare(i, oldSubstring.length(), oldSubstring) == 0)
                s.replace(i, oldSubstring.length(), newSubstring);
    }

    std::cout << s;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!! )

Answer (score 2):

Ты должен идти по строке, при этом считая количество уже встретившихся кавычек. Как только встречаешь нужное тебе слово, то заменяешь его только в том случае если количество уже встретившихся кавычек четно.

Comment: Только надо не забывать отслеживать экранированные (например, как тут: `"...\"..."`) кавычки

Comment: @avp а об экранированных в исходной задаче ничего не сказано)

Comment: @andreymal, никогда не помешает смотреть хотя бы на шаг вперед...